# ICS file showing show as "Free" and "Busy" Status not getting properly in outlook app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, outlook, icalendar

i need to send ICS file with Status Show as "Basy" or "Free" (configure based on method) using ICAL.NET 'https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net', i passed Status in CalendarEvent, web portal showing correct status but outlook app (window/mobile) is showing always "Busy" status

```
var e = new CalendarEvent 
        {
            Status = Status,
            Start = new CalDateTime(startDate),
            End = new CalDateTime(endDate),
            Summary = eventTitle,
        };
```

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20220308T170000
DTSTAMP:20220301T074736Z
DTSTART:20220308T080000
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:FREE
SUMMARY:Basic User - Holiday Booking
UID:cceeab8c-a9d5-43a4-adae-f784c0acefe3
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

please any have solution or other nuget packages, whose working fine, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook, you need `X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS` header. The possible values are `FREE`, `WORKINGELSEWHERE`, `TENTATIVE`, `BUSY`, `OOF`.

The standard header name is `TRANSP` (Outlook can use it too) - the values are `TRANSPARENT` or `OPAQUE`. In the latter case, you can also set `STATUS` to `TENTATIVE`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmitry Streblechenko, its working fine when i add this line  `e.AddProperty("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS", Status);`